# How to update twenty columns set default value 0 respectively where columns are null in one table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to update twenty columns set default value 0 respectively where columns are null in one table in MySQL?

such as I write SQL as below(every columns are varchar field):

```
update table set a = 0 where a is Null;
update table set b = 0 where b is Null;
...
...
update table set x = 0 where x is Null;
```

Comment: Do you actually want the columns to have a default value (in SQL, that's a value used if no value is supplied at insert time, which is different from being given an explicit NULL at insert time)? If so, you need to update the table definition, not just the data.

Comment: If the columns are VARCHAR, surely your 'default' value should be a varchar? (`'0'` rather than `0`?)

Comment: What is the specific problem with the solution you have tried?

Comment: @MatBailie '0' or 0 is ok for me, no matter the columns are varchar or num, I think that does not affect the effect of what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
SET a = COALESCE(a, '0'),
    b = COALESCE(b, '0'),
--  ...
    z = COALESCE(z, '0');
```

`'0'`, not `0`, is used because you tell that column types are VARCHAR.

Comment: The op then commented that some columns are 'num', and asserted that it doesn't matter.  (If they already know better than the people being asked for advice, why bother asking for advice?)

Comment: @MatBailie In practice it doesn't matter. On-NULL assigned value is a constant, and it is converted to correct datatype during execution plan building, i.e. once, not during the query execution.